# Moving backgrounds

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

So i want to have a moving background for my PC so i tried out a c++ code i made. The code i used doesn't allow me to use gifs so instead made layers of animation and the program would keep on changing the background image to create a moving background. The issue is that this program uses too much cpu usage and cause the image to lag. So i want to know if there is any way around this using c++. I know i could use some other program but i want to learn a little c++ especially programs that interact with the operating system.

```
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)"image01.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE );
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)"image02.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE );
```

Also i have about 23 frames.

Comment: I think that Windows internally converts the image into BMP. Maybe if your images are of BMP format and of the proper size and bit-depth you will avoid a lot of CPU work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Sleep()` function to give back some CPU usage time to Windows.

The `Sleep()`  function causes a thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice and become unrunnable for an interval based on the value of dwMilliseconds. The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time.

After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){

  Sleep(100);  //100 Milliseconds or 0.1 seconds
  return 0;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396